# Is it possible to have a parent state without having its name in the URL?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I used the App template [ionic-starter-sidemenu](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu/blob/master/js/app.js) to start an App.

This App template uses parent states with the [dot notation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#dot-notation) to include the menu in the child states.

Is it possible to do this in a way that makes the child states available at URLs like "/a-child-state" instead of "/the-parent-state/a-child-state"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. This is easily possible by removing the ["url" property](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu/blob/master/js/app.js#L29)
from the parent's declaration altogether. Setting it to

```
url: "/"
```

won't work (though setting it to an empty string works, too).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just declare a state without a parent. The menu is an abstract state and its children are declared with PARENT.CHILD - this enables the back button to work its magic.

```
$stateProvider
 .state('login', {
    cache: false, 
    url: '/login',
    cache: false,
    templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  });
```

Just call $state.go anywhere except config.

```
$state.go('login');
```

Comment: But isn't the parent state used in the App template I used to inherit the [menu](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu/blob/master/templates/menu.html) to the child states and I this would result in a state without the menu showing up?

Comment: Oh yeah - good point. Copy and paste the menu from index.html into the login.html. Login will now have its own standalone menu.